# Python multiprocessing.Process object behaves like it would hold a reference to an object in another process. Why?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, shared-memory

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def delay_one_second(event):
    print 'in SECONDARY process, preparing to wait for 1 second'
    event.wait(1)
    print 'in the SECONDARY process, preparing to raise the event'
    event.set()

if __name__=='__main__':
    evt = mp.Event()
    print 'preparing to wait 10 seconds in the PRIMARY process'
    mp.Process(target = delay_one_second, args=(evt,)).start()
    evt.wait(10)
    print 'PRIMARY process, waking up'
```

This code (run nicely from inside a module with the "python module.py" command inside cmd.exe) yields a surprising result.

The main process apparently only waits for 1 second before waking up. For this to happen, it means that the secondary process has a reference to an object in the main process.

How can this be? I was expecting to have to use a multiprocessing.Manager(), to share objects between processes, but how is this possible?

I mean the Processes are not threads, they shouldn't use the same memory space. Anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the shared memory is not managed by a separate process; it's managed by the operating system itself.

You can see how this works if you spend some time browsing through the `multiprocessing` source. You'll see that an [`Event`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#l299) object uses a [`Semaphore`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#l108) and a [`Condition`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#l195), both of which rely on the locking behavior provided by the [`SemLock`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#l72) object. This, in turn, wraps a [`_multiprocessing.SemLock`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c) object, which is implemented in c and depends on either [`sem_open`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#l195) (POSIX) or [`CreateSemaphore`](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#l35) (Windows).

These are c functions that enable access to shared resources that are managed by the operating system itself -- in this case, named semaphores. They can be shared between threads *or* processes; the OS takes care of everything. What happens is that when a new semaphore is created, it is given a *handle*. Then, when a new process that needs access to that semaphore is created, it's given a copy of the handle. It then passes that handle to [`sem_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) or [`CreateSemapohre`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the operating system gives the new process access to the original semaphore.

So the memory *is* being shared, but it's being shared as part of the operating system's built-in support for synchronization primitives. In other words, in this case, you don't need to open a new process to manage the shared memory; the operating system takes over that task. But this is only possible because `Event` doesn't need anything more complex than a semaphore to work.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that the *multiprocessing* module follows the threading API. My guess would be that it uses a mechanism similar to 'fork'. If you fork a thread your OS will create a copy of the current process. It means that it copies the heap and stack, including all your variables and globals and that's what you're seeing.

<del>You can see it for yourself if you pass the function below to a new process.</del>

```
def print_globals():
    print globals()
```

Comment: printing the globals wouldn't help much, AFAIK, it would obviously give the same result (well pretty much). What would help is printing the `id` of the objects. I did that, and they aren't the same.... it looks to me like the event objects are somehow mapped between processes, cuz of course, in the secondary process, an unpickeld Event is being set, which is not the same as the non-pickeled event in the main process

Comment: @vlad-ardelean Processes can share memory addresses, but as you've pointed out, the results of `repr(event)` actually show that the memory addresses are diffent. What these two instances of `Event` have in common is the same internal semaphore, making possible the synchronization between processes.

Comment: @A.Rodas though the `id(evt._cond)` and `id(evt._flag)` also return different results, i understand that these can be proxies of a C object which could indeed be  the same. It's not intuitive that it's like this, but apparently that's how it is. It seems weird that this would happen, since there are Manager objects, meant to manage instances of Event - which one would think are the "real" shared events. And it also makes sense for events to be shared out of the box, since they wouldn't be useful otherwise.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean Of course you are right. I haven't given it much thought before posting it.

Comment: @Michal no worries, thx for trying to help :) the issue was less than trivial, so it's understandable to miss some things.